# Нужны ли запятые в предложении? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика, запятые

Можно выбрать(,) открыть все окна(,) или лишь главные.

Answer (score 4):

**Можно выбрать: открыть все окна или лишь главные.**

Или: **Можно выбрать ― открыть все окна или лишь главные.**

Вторая часть предложения поясняет первую, поэтому ставится двоеточие или тире.

Одиночный союз ИЛИ соединяет однородные члены, поэтому запятая не ставится.